# Integrate Azure DevOps to Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops

I have set up Jenkins in Azure VM. Now, How can I integrate Azure DevOps Service hook to Jenkins. I want to trigger Jenkins Job when anyone pushes the code in the Azure DevOps repository. I am getting below error "**Jenkins query failed with exception 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time Or Established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'**" while setup service hook. I have gone through the "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops" link but it's not working.

Comment: your jenkins should be accessible externally

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thank You for response !!! can you give me link for more information If you have?

Comment: information on what? the definition of accessible externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Integrate Azure DevOps to Jenkins

According to the error messages, it shows that Azure devops did not successfully connect Jenkins.

To resolve this issue, just like 4c74356b41 commented, you should make sure you could access the Jenkins from the public internet. You can check following document for some more details:

[How to Host Jenkins on Azure](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/04/jenkins-on-azure/)

Then you can add Jenkins queue job task in the pipeline, and verify the connection via this task:

[image]

Hope this helps.