# Triggering an azure devops pipeline from Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines

I’m trying to trigger an azure devops pipeline from Jenkins and a bit stuck given some constraints.

I initially wanted to leverage option 2 here, using a service connection here to run a build on Jenkins and trigger a deployment pipeline following the completion of the Jenkins build job

### Problem

Can’t set up the service connection because the Jenkins box, while hosted in azure, is not open to the internet so the service connection can’t hit it

Alternatively there is the option to use the Jenkins azure artifacts plug-in to upload artifacts into blob storage but not sure how to pull that down from blob storage or use it as a trigger for a pipeline

Any workaround to have Jenkins trigger an azure devops pipeline?

The recommendation in this post is to have the Jenkins box be publicly accessible but that is not going to happen, is this idea dead in the water?
[Integrate Azure DevOps to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967986/integrate-azure-devops-to-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

> The recommendation in this post is to have the Jenkins box be publicly accessible but that is not going to happen, is this idea dead in the water?

If your Jenkins box is not open to the internet, I am afraid you could not achieve that trigger an azure devops pipeline from Jenkins.

Just as you know, since the Jenkins box is not open to the internet, so we could not create service connection to connect azure devops to jenkins, then we can't use this to send trigger messages that notify the azure pipeline.

On other side, since the Jenkins box is not open to the internet, we could not upload artifacts into blob storage(This requires you to have an external network to access azure resources).

On the other hand, even though we can upload artifacts into blob storage, there is currently no setup for a build/release pipeline based on artifacts triggered：

[image]